# Django object not saving all iterations of a recursive save method

Tags: python, django, recursion

I have a recursive save method in my Django project to create multiple instances of calendar events; the problem is only the last event actually seems to get saved. I'm either missing something obvious, or there's an obscure bit of Django wizardy I'm not familiar with.

ETA: As an example, if I have an event on the first Friday of a month for three months, only the third month will actually save to the database.

Save method is below and related functions are below:

```
def move_to_next_month(sent_date):
    temp_date = sent_date.replace(tzinfo=None)
    if temp_date.month != 12:
        temp_date = temp_date.replace(month=temp_date.month + 1, day=1)
        return temp_date
    else:
       temp_date = temp_date.replace(year=temp_date.year + 1, month=1, day=1)
        return temp_date

def date_checker(temp_date, day_of_week, week_of_month):
    if week_of_month == "first":
        return temp_date.weekday() == day_of_week and 0 < temp_date.day < 8
    if week_of_month == "second":
        return temp_date.weekday() == day_of_week and 7 < temp_date.day < 15
    if week_of_month == "third":
        return temp_date.weekday() == day_of_week and 14 < temp_date.day < 22
    if week_of_month == "fourth":
        return temp_date.weekday() == day_of_week and 21 < temp_date.day < 28

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if not self.orig_title:
        self.orig_title = self.title
    if self.end_date is None:
        self.end_date = self.start_date
    tempSlug = slugify("%s %s %s" % (self.orig_title, self.start_date.strftime("%b %d %Y"), self.branch))
    self.slug = tempSlug
    if not self.pk:
        self.is_repeating = repeating_event_check(self)
        super(MonthlyRepeatingEvent, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        if self.number_of_repetitions > 1:
            temp_start_date = move_to_next_month(self.start_date)
            temp_end_date = move_to_next_month(self.end_date)
            next_repetition = self
            next_repetition.pk = None
            next_repetition.end_date = temp_end_date
            next_repetition.start_date = temp_start_date
            next_repetition.number_of_repetitions = self.number_of_repetitions - 1
            while not date_checker(next_repetition.start_date,next_repetition.day_of_week,next_repetition.week_of_month):
                next_repetition.start_date = next_repetition.start_date.replace(tzinfo=None) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            while not date_checker(next_repetition.end_date,next_repetition.day_of_week,next_repetition.week_of_month):
                next_repetition.end_date = next_repetition.end_date.replace(tzinfo=None) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            next_slug = slugify("%s %s %s" % (next_repetition.orig_title, next_repetition.start_date.strftime("%b %d %Y"), next_repetition.branch))
            next = MonthlyRepeatingEvent.objects.filter(slug=next_slug).first()
            if next is not None:
                 next_repetition.pk = next.pk
                 next_repetition.slug = next_slug
                 next.delete()
                 next_repetition.save()
            else:
                 next_repetition.slug = next_slug
                 next_repetition.save()
    else:
        super(MonthlyRepeatingEvent, self).save(*args,**kwargs)
        if self.number_of_repetitions > 1:
            temp_start_date = move_to_next_month(self.start_date)
            temp_end_date = move_to_next_month(self.end_date)
            next_repetition = self
            next_repetition.pk = None
            next_repetition.end_date = temp_end_date
            next_repetition.start_date = temp_start_date
            next_repetition.number_of_repetitions = self.number_of_repetitions - 1
            while not date_checker(next_repetition.start_date,next_repetition.day_of_week,next_repetition.week_of_month):
                next_repetition.start_date = next_repetition.start_date.replace(tzinfo=None) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            while not date_checker(next_repetition.end_date,next_repetition.day_of_week,next_repetition.week_of_month):
                next_repetition.end_date = next_repetition.end_date.replace(tzinfo=None) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
            next_slug = slugify("%s %s %s" % (next_repetition.orig_title, next_repetition.start_date.strftime("%b %d %Y"), next_repetition.branch))
            next = MonthlyRepeatingEvent.objects.filter(slug=next_slug).first()
            if next is not None:
                 next_repetition.pk = next.pk
                 next_repetition.slug = next_slug
                 next.delete()
                 next_repetition.save()
            else:
                 next_repetition.slug = next_slug
                 next_repetition.save()
```

ETA: updated code is below

```
class MonthlyRepeatingEvent(Event):
    day_of_week = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0, choices=DAY_OPTIONS,blank=True,null=True)
    week_of_month = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=WEEK_OPTIONS,blank=True,null=True)
    number_of_repetitions = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=0)

def create_new_instance(instance):
    temp_start_date = move_to_next_month(instance.start_date)
    temp_end_date = move_to_next_month(instance.end_date)
    next_repetition = instance
    next_repetition.pk = None
    next_repetition.end_date = temp_end_date
    next_repetition.start_date = temp_start_date
    next_repetition.number_of_repetitions = instance.number_of_repetitions - 1
    while not date_checker(next_repetition.start_date,next_repetition.day_of_week,next_repetition.week_of_month):
        next_repetition.start_date = next_repetition.start_date.replace(tzinfo=None) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    while not date_checker(next_repetition.end_date,next_repetition.day_of_week,next_repetition.week_of_month):
        next_repetition.end_date = next_repetition.end_date.replace(tzinfo=None) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    next_slug = slugify("%s %s %s" % (next_repetition.orig_title, next_repetition.start_date.strftime("%b %d %Y"), next_repetition.branch))
    next = MonthlyRepeatingEvent.objects.filter(slug=next_slug).first()
    if next is not None:
        print("Delete function called.")
        next.delete()
    print("Save function called")   
    next_repetition.save()

@receiver(post_save, sender=MonthlyRepeatingEvent)
    def repeater(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if instance.number_of_repetitions > 1:
        create_new_instance(instance)
```

Comment: A first step towards debugging would always include not using blank `excepts` (like in NEVER use those at all)! At least print/log the exception message/type. It might come from your database and have broken a larger transaction...

Comment: I have a hard time following your code, but there is one obvious issue you should correct: You have a naked try/except that swallows all exceptions. Your code may be raising an exception you are not expecting. I think you are trying to catch an `ObjectDoesNotExist` exception that would be raised by `MonthlyRepeatingEvent.objects.get(slug=next_slug)`. You could instead do `MonthlyRepeatingEvent.objects.filter(slug=next_slug).first()` which will return `None` if there is no match. You can then check if it returned None or not.

Comment: @NikHaldimann - I integrated your suggestion. It's definitely cleaner code, but the initial problem remains where only one instance of the repetition is saving.

Comment: Overriding the save method to do this operation is a very hacky solution. And the fact that you get a bug that you can't figure out is a sign that you are making it too complicated. You can move this repetition stuff into one or more functions. You have multiple nested if-blocks, which makes it really hard to reason about what's going on. There's also a lot of code repetition in the two main if-else blocks.

Comment: Add some logging in the method. Check how many times the `save` method is called, and whether `next.delete()` is called. You might be deleting some of the instances immediately after creating them.

Comment: @HåkenLid - I pulled the repetition code out into a separate function and hooked it to a post_save signal that sends the saved instance to use as a reference for content. Logging shows the save method in the repetition code is only called once. The delete method is never called.

Comment: Try to isolate the code that causes the bug. There's so much in your question, so it's hard to spot what could go wrong. [mcve]

Comment: @HåkenLid - Thanks for the advice. I'll strip it down to the basic parts and see if I can find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost - thanks to the commenters for their tips - that helped clean up my code considerably, which in turn aided with troubleshooting.

When I duplicated the repeating function  in a simplified form, it worked perfectly, indicating the problem was not in the logic behind the function; the primary difference between the simplified object and the one in the original query is the simplified object inherited directly from `models.Model`, and the original query object used inheritance from a base `Event` object.

And, in fact, the answer has to do with inheritance and Django models:

[Making Queries|Django documentation|Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#copying-model-instances)

When you create a copy of an object instance from a class that uses inheritance, you have to declare both `instance.pk = None` and `instance.id = None`.

Accordingly, the function to create repetition would be:

```
def create_mre_new_instance(instance):
    temp_start_date = move_to_next_month(instance.start_date)
    temp_end_date = move_to_next_month(instance.end_date)
    next_repetition = instance
    next_repetition.start_date = temp_start_date
    next_repetition.end_date = temp_end_date
    next_repetition.number_of_repetitions = instance.number_of_repetitions - 1
    while not date_checker(next_repetition.start_date,next_repetition.day_of_week,next_repetition.week_of_month):
        next_repetition.start_date = next_repetition.start_date.replace(tzinfo=None) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    while not date_checker(next_repetition.end_date,next_repetition.day_of_week,next_repetition.week_of_month):
        next_repetition.end_date = next_repetition.end_date.replace(tzinfo=None) + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    next_slug = slugify("%s %s %s" % (next_repetition.orig_title, next_repetition.start_date.strftime("%b %d %Y"), next_repetition.branch))
    next = MonthlyRepeatingEvent.objects.filter(slug=next_slug).first()
    if next is not None:
        next.delete()
    next_repetition.pk = None
    next_repetition.id = None
    next_repetition.save()
```